# Where does this refractive index formula come from: $n_{1} = n - 1 = \frac{77.6P}{T} 10^{-6}$

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, atmosphere-modelling, atmospheric-radiation

In this equation, $n_{1} = n - 1 = \frac{77.6P}{T} \cdot 10^{-6}$ the variable P is the total air pressure and T is expressed in Kelvin. This equation describes the refractive index of moist air as EM waves pass through.

This formula appears in [Roggemann & Welsh from 1996](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Imaging_Through_Turbulence.html?id=nuIC-Mk0R4UC), but a similar version existed in [1953 (Smith, Weintraub)](https://archive.org/details/jresv50n1p39/mode/2up). The current literature uses this formula extensively but its never been properly explained.

Comment: https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/p/R-REC-P.453-6-199705-S!!PDF-E.pdf suggests it's based on observation and curve fitting.

Answer (score 3):

The index of refraction for air [scales linearly with density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index#Density), and the density in an idea gas is proportional to pressure and inversely proportional to temperature. Under typical atmospheric conditions, dry air is reasonably ideal, so we can write:

$$n_{1} = n - 1 = \frac{(n_0-1) T_0}{P_0}\frac{P}{T}$$

where $n_0$ is the index of refraction at some reference temperature $T_0$ and pressure $P_0$.

[Smith and Weintraub](https://archive.org/details/jresv50n1p39/mode/2up) used a value of $n_0-1 = 288.04\times10^{-6}$ which was the average of 3 published values for visible, 9 GHz, and 24 GHz electromagnetic radiation measured at $T_0 = 273\,\textrm{K}$ and $P_0 = 1013.15\,\textrm{mb}$, which gives

$$n_{1} = n - 1 = 77.6\times 10^{-6} \frac{P}{T}$$

(I figured this out while wrestling with a similar commonly-used but obscurely-sourced equation relevant to my own question ["How distant is the horizon on Venus?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/732028/how-distant-is-the-horizon-on-venus).)